# Last child border in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In React, there are various ways to access and style the last child. However, I have not seen any example to do that.

I would appreciate it if you guys could suggest any options.

Comment: can you include some reference about the last child you are talking about, A [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help us to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ListView or Column with a known number of children, and you want to style the last child differently, you can use the children property and access the last child by its index.

```
ListView(
  children: [
    // Other children
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      ListTile(
        title: Text(items[i]),
        // Style the last child differently
        tileColor: i == items.length - 1 ? Colors.blue : null,
      ),
  ],
)
```

If you are using ListView.builder or have dynamic children in a Column, you can use a condition to determine if the current item is the last child.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(items[index]),
      // Style the last child differently
      tileColor: index == items.length - 1 ? Colors.blue : null,
    );
  },
)
```